# Dropdown sin funcionar y containerfluid que no debería tener márgenes con Bootstrap4

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Mi problema es que en el navbar, el dropdown no me está funcionando y no entiendo por qué si lo estoy haciendo igual a la documentación. Me funcionó hace 1 hora y ahora no

Y el otro problema es que estoy intentando colocar una imagen con `<div class="container-fluid">` que debería tomar todo el ancho de la pantalla, pero me está dejando un pequeño margen.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Este es el código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.pcmag.com/sm/pcmagus/photo/default/podio-logo_swc1.png" width="150" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top img-fluid" alt="">
      </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="container mr-5">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Funciones</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Precios</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Casos de usos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reservar una demo</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#seccion1">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Registrate</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://cursosformacionseguros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fondoAtenci%C3%B3n-y-fidelizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-en-redes-sociales-en-seguros.-Social-CRM-y-social-loyalty-en-seguros.jpg" alt="">
</div>  
<!-- End slider -->
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Disculpen era dropwdown no scroll down

Comment: en vez de comentarlo, usá el enlace para **[edit]** al pie de tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Mira este es un ejemplo de como hacer uno, adáptalo a ti agregando las opciones

la forma de llamar los script es distinto esta dentro del body o dentro del head 
los script de js van al pie y los css van en el head, solo como buen práctica

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Landing Page</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
</nav>
   </div>
  
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://cursosformacionseguros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fondoAtenci%C3%B3n-y-fidelizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-en-redes-sociales-en-seguros.-Social-CRM-y-social-loyalty-en-seguros.jpg" alt="">
</div>  
<!-- End slider -->
<!--Script seccion--->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!---end script---->

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te está dando el siguiente error:

> TypeError: t is undefined

Esto ocurre poruqe has insertado antes el `javascript` de `bootstrap` que el `jQuery`, para solucionarlo cambia el orden de los scripts, pon primero `jQuery`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <img src="https://www.pcmag.com/sm/pcmagus/photo/default/podio-logo_swc1.png" width="150" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top img-fluid" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="container mr-5">
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Funciones</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Precios</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Casos de usos</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reservar una demo</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#seccion1">Login</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Registrate</button>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>

<!-- Slider -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-warning">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="http://cursosformacionseguros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fondoAtenci%C3%B3n-y-fidelizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-en-redes-sociales-en-seguros.-Social-CRM-y-social-loyalty-en-seguros.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<!-- End slider -->
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```